# segmentation fault on mysql_close

Tags: c++, mysql, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, macos-sierra

On my Mac (Sierra 10.12.4) I'm getting errors in a C++ program upon closing a MySQL DB connection.

The two error messages I get are

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe1b2d81800: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Most of the time one of these will occur, but it's not possible to tell beforehand when or which one.

Although the first error gives some indication as to what might be going on, I've not been able to pin point the underlying issue. The DB connection is set up near the start of the program by the two lines

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

and I'm calling

```
mysql_close(conn);
```

only once towards the end of my program. This is where the error occurs.
The connection itself is working fine. In fact, I'm writing some log data to the DB immediately prior to closing the connection.

I have also tried to debug the program, but that's been fraught with problems in itself. Happy to post what I tried though if this issue can't be resolved otherwise.

Note that the errors started on my Mac only after the recent update to 10.12.4. Prior to this, the same code ran without any issues, and it sill compiles and runs fine on Linux.

Comment: Do you, by chance, overwrite where `conn` points to?

Comment: Does it give you this error if you - just for a try - close the connection immediately after having opened it, too?

Comment: Looks like a classic case of undefined behaviour to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver: To be 100% sure, I just double-checked this by printing the pointer address before and after that final write to DB. As expected, the pointer doesn't change.

Comment: @JohnS. -- How about just opening and then immediately closing?  If that works, then it is something in between that is being done that is causing the issue.  A pointer address being the same doesn't mean anything if something else has corrupted the memory (or has inadvertently freed the memory, and you're freeing the same memory again).

Comment: @StephanLechner, PaulMcKenzie: Done some more testing, and the behaviour I get is pretty random. Independently of where in the code I close the DB connection, sometimes it's fine and sometimes it isn't. I also checked (again) whether I unintentionally free the memory, but I'm certain I don't. Moreover, if I never close the connection, the program runs fine. Surely this wouldn't be recommended though?!

Comment: What I suggested was a test.  Just open and immediately close the connection.  If there is no issue with that, then the issue is something being done in your actual code in between opening and closing that is causing the problem.  Random behavior suggests you're doing something wrong that is causing undefined / random behavior, otherwise thousands of programmers would have reported a bug in the mysql library you're using.

Comment: I finally tracked the issue down to a piece of code where I somewhat cumbersomely converted a std::string mystring to a char* via strcpy, and then to an unsigned char* using a reinterpret_cast. I'm now simply doing (unsigned char*) mystring.c_str(), and the errors are gone!